# after calling exec

Tags: linux

After calling exec, is it possible to print a message, because I tried and nothing happened. I read some articles about exec but I couldn't find my answer. It replaces the process image with a new one but not creating a new process. Is it something about it? Does it wait for something I mean if I use it in child process, so does it wait for ending child process?

I can give this example:

```
char *args[6] = { "cat","-b","-t","-v",argv[1],0};

else if(pid == 0){
printf("Child Process ID:%d, Parent ID:%d, Process
Group:%d\n",getpid(),getppid(),getgid());
execv("/bin/cat",args);
printf("AHMET TANAKOL\n");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - it sounds to me there is a better way of doing this

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean but i never used linux until this time this is why I don't know many things

Comment: Thats cool - but what is your intention. Also give example of the programs you want to run - there maybe API ways to get the result or other options. ie I want to write a program that runs another program and the output of the 2nd program  is visible in my terminal.

Comment: I think you want me to be more clear when I'm asking questions. Ok i'll try, but I generally work on same code and maybe people are bored from my questions. But I will try to make my questions more understandable

Comment: Nope, it is not possible. Only case in which the printf will be printed is when `execv` fails, otherwise the statements after this call is never executed. This trick is used by developers for printing error on failure of `exec` set of calls like: `execv("/bin/cat",args); perror("execv");`. So that error is printed in case `execv` fails. To check this change `/bin/cat` to something like `/bin/cat_i_dont_exist` in `execv`

Comment: @AhmetTanakol: Because AFAIK that is the way exec family of APIs are designed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exec` family, like you already read, *replaces* the process image. That is, it loads the new program, removes your program, and start running the new program in place of your program.

No call to `exec` functions ever returns, unless there is an error.